# Obtener valor de python desde php

Tags: php, python

Estoy intentando obtener un valor desde `PHP` llamando a un script en `Python`, pero me devuelve un array vacío

Es extraño porque si hago un **print("Test")** en `Python` si que devuelve el valor

El script en python funciona bien desde consola ejecutanto:

> $ python3 getTemperature.py

```html
import time 
import board 
import adafruit_dht
#Initial the dht device, with data pin connected to: 
dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT11(board.D2)
temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
humidity = dhtDevice.humidity

print("Temp: {:.1f} C Humidity: {}% " .format(temperature_c, humidity))
```

```html
exec('python3 /var/www/html/home/getTemperature.py', $output, $ret_code);

print_r($output);
print_r($ret_code);
```

Comment: Posiblemente te fallen los import que tienes al inicio del script. Eso puede pasar si esos módulos los instalaste para una versión de python diferente de la que encuentra PHP. Mira desde consola qué python estás ejecutando (`which python3`) y pon la ruta completa a ese ejecutable en el PHP.

Comment: Por cierto, no es muy buena idea poner código en la carpeta `html`, pues cualquiera podría descargarse el fuente del script Python accediendo a `http://tu.servidor.com/home/getTemperature.py`. Quizás en este caso eso no sea muy importante pero otras veces los scripts pueden contener secretos, como api_keys, etc.

Comment: Ejecutando which python3 y cambiando la ruta por: exec('/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/html/home/getTemperature.py', $output, $ret_code); sigue sin sacarme el valor

Comment: Tienes forma de capturar desde PHP la salida de error además de la salida estándar? Así verías si imprime algo por ese otro lado. ¿Y qué obtienes en `$ret_code`?

Comment: $ret_code imprime 1, estoy buscando información sobre ese código de error pero no encuentro nada

Comment: Ni lo vas a encontrar ya que lo que hay ahí es el código de salida de python, que es lo que se le haya pasado a la llamada `sys.exit()` desde el script. Ya que tú no tienes esa llamada, significa que ha sido el propio intérprete el que lo ha hecho. Esos códigos no están estandarizados, salvo que 0 significa "todo ha ido bien" y distinto de cero es algún problema (pero cada programa elige qué significan sus números). Intenta añadir `2> /tmp/errores` a la llamada, para encontrar luego en `/tmp/errores` la traza de la excepción que se haya producido.